# TypeError: Unable to serialize datetime.time. Django, Dsl elasticsearch, Python

Tags: python, django, django-filter, elasticsearch-dsl

i have a document with

late_delivery = ObJectField()

```
"late_delivery": {
   "City": {
      "delivery_time": TimeField,
      "order_time": TimeField,
   }
}
```

example:

```
"late_delivery": {
    "SomeCity": {
        "delivery_time": "23:00:00",
        "order_time": "22:00:00",
   },
```

and i wanna filter queryset by datetime.time, that less than now

i tried

```
class LateDeliveryFilter(BaseFilterBackend):

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        
        late_delivery_requested = request.data.get("late_delivery", None)
        if not late_delivery_requested:
           return queryset

        now = datetime.now().time()

        queryset = queryset.filter(fulfillment=RB_STOCK)
        kwargs = {
            f"late_delivery__{settings.CITY_NAME}__order_time": {"lt": now}
        }
        return queryset.filter("range",  **kwargs)
```

but i'm getting an error

```
TypeError("Unable to serialize datetime.time(12, 51, 22, 708584) (type: <class 'datetime.time'>)"))
```

can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The time object needs to be formatted to ISO 8501 String for Elasticsearch indexing to work for example.

Try this:

`now = datetime.now().time().isoformat()`